# Create a route that maps the url /messages to the Messages controller's index action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have generated a controller called Messages, now in the route file I have to map the URL /messages to the Messages controller's index action.

```
def index

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
get '/messages' => 'messages#index', as: :messages
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It will work for sure!

```
get '/messages' => 'messages#index'
```